# UPDATE or DELETE parent

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to create a table appointment that has attributes idAppointment,idDoctor,TimeFrom,TimeTo,Day. The doctor creates an appointment that the patient can choose (see PatientAppointment table). Day is 0 - Monday, 1- Tuesday ...

Doctor

| idDoctor | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Jack |
| 2 | Alex |

Patient

| idPatient | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Sam |
| 2 | Cris |

Apointment // created by doctor

| idAppointment | idDoctor | timeFrom | timeTo | day |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 6:00 | 7:00 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | 8:00 | 9:00 | 3 |

PatientAppointment

| idPatientApintment | idAppointment | date | idPatient |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 24-01-22 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 26-01-22 | 2 |

How can the doctor UPDATE or DELETE row in the Appointment table, but the PatientAppointment table remains unchanged.

Comment: What are the `CREATE TABLE` statements, in particular the foreign key definitions?

Comment: create table Apointment(

idAppointment serial primary key,
idDoctor int references doctor(iddoctor),
timeFrom timestamp,
timeTo timestamp,
day int);

create table PatientAppointment(
idPatientApintment serial primary key,
idAppointment int references apointment(idapointment),
date date,
idpatinet int references patient(idpatient)
);

Comment: Please [edit] the question and add the information there.

Comment: For appointments I would a range type datatype, like tsrange, and a constraint to avoid conflicts: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-CONSTRAINT